# What kind of algorithm does Mathematica use to find limits?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, implementation-details

Is there any information available about the implementation of the `Limit` command? In particular, I am interested in how Mathematica computes limits of real functions involving basic arithmetic, `Log`, and `Exp`.

The approach that I know is to compute some kind of asymptotic expansion (using multiseries or nested expansions), as detailed e.g. in [Dominik Gruntz's PhD thesis](http://e-collection.library.ethz.ch/eserv/eth:40284/eth-40284-02.pdf), the book [‘Symbolic Asymptotics’](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540210979) by John Shackell, or [various papers](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00073832) by Salvy/Richardson/Shackell/van der Hoeven.

My guess is that Mathematica uses something like this for that class of functions, but I wonder whether there are any more details available.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html says only "Limits are found from series and using other methods."

Comment: One of those other methods is an implementation of Gruntz's algorithm. This was done by Adam Strzebonski around 2008.

Comment: Very interesting! Do you have a citable source for that? I.e. that Mathematica actually uses this?

Comment: Maybe you can poke around using `Trace`? But probably the function's implementation is all-internal...

Comment: @ManuelEberl  According to his LinkedIn profile, Daniel Lichtblau has worked for Wolfram for 25 years, and is currently with the Kernel Research Group, focusing on the "development and implementation of algorithms for mathematical computation."  So he himself probably qualifies as the citable source you seek.

Comment: Well I can, of course, cite this as ‘personal communication’, but a written document would be nicer. In any case, thanks for pointing out who he is; I wasn't aware that he was actually with Wolfram.